# How to replace specific vector values?

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace a long vector values such as:

- if the value is equal to 1 , 2 or 3 then it will be replaced by 1.
- if the value is equal to 6 , 7 , 8  then it will be replaced by 2.
- if the value is equal to 4 , 5 , 9 then it will be replaced by 3.

I tried the following but it doesn't give the expected output:

```
set.seed(1)
x=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),size=15,replace=TRUE)
print("step1")
x
as.numeric(gsub(c(1,2,3), 1, x))
as.numeric(gsub(c(6,7,8), 2, x))
as.numeric(gsub(c(4,5,9), 3, x))
print("step2")

x
```

I obtained the following:

```
[1] "step1"

    3 4 6 9 2 9 9 6 6 1 2 2 7 4 7

Warning message in gsub(c(1, 2, 3), 1, x):
"l'argument pattern a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé"

    3 4 6 9 2 9 9 6 6 1 2 2 7 4 7

Warning message in gsub(c(6, 7, 8), 2, x):
"l'argument pattern a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé"

    3 4 2 9 2 9 9 2 2 1 2 2 7 4 7

Warning message in gsub(c(4, 5, 9), 3, x):
"l'argument pattern a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé"

    3 3 6 9 2 9 9 6 6 1 2 2 7 3 7

[1] "step2"

    3 4 6 9 2 9 9 6 6 1 2 2 7 4 7
```

To be more exact, I'm wanting to replace a set of values like `{6,7,8}` in a vector x with one specific value like `2`.

I hope my question is clear, I tried solutions from similar questions but I didn't obtain the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replacing scheme. The vector `xori` has the original values whereas `x` has been changed with different conditions. Additionally, the shortcut `1:3` is equivalent to `c(1,2,3)`. Here the code:

```
#Code
set.seed(1)
x=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),size=15,replace=TRUE)
xori <- x
#Replace
x[x %in% 1:3]<-1
x[x %in% 6:8]<-2
x[x %in% c(4,5,9)]<-3
#Print
xori
x
```

Output:

```
xori
 [1] 9 4 7 1 2 7 2 3 1 5 5 6 7 9 5
x
 [1] 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 3 3
```

If one way is required:

```
#One way
x <- ifelse(x %in% 1:3,1,
            ifelse(x %in% 6:8,2,
                   ifelse(x %in% c(4,5,9),3,NA)))
```

Output:

```
x
 [1] 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: this helps a lot . Thank you for your valuable help !

Answer (score 1):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(x %in% 1:3 ~ 1, x %in% 6:8 ~ 2, x %in% c(4, 5, 9) ~ 3)
#[1] 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 3 3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),size=15,replace=TRUE)
```